# Context menu is not working properly when in VStack that's in a List in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, list, swiftui

First, I'd like to emphasize that with a `ScrollView` instead of `List`, this issue doesn't happen.

I have created this test code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            VStack { //this VStack messes up the context menu 
                Button("1", action: {})
                    .contextMenu {
                        Button {
                            print("hi")
                        } label: {
                            Text("test")
                        }
                    }
                Button("2", action: {})
                    .contextMenu {
                        Button {
                            print("hi")
                        } label: {
                            Text("test")
                        }
                    }

            
            Image(systemName: "globe")
                .imageScale(.large)
                .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
            Text("Hello, world!")
        }
    }
    .padding()
}
```

}

The result when long pressing to show the context menu is that the whole `VStack` is the context menu (instead of just the button)[image: this is the bug]

Also attaching what is looks like when I comment out the VStack:

[image: this works but I need the VStack]

Is this an Apple bug? is there a way to get this to work with the VStack? In my real app, I have many sections with horizontal stacks and obviously a real app cannot be built without VStack or HStack (lazy or not)

Comment: The VStack is denoting to the compiler that everything inside this stack is this one single list row. Because of this, it is going to treat the entire VStack as a single row - thus resulting in the behavior you mentioned. This level of customizability is probably exceeding the main purpose of a list. Is there a reason you are trying to throw all those items into a single list row?

Comment: @nickreps thanks for the response. Yes, there is a reason. Actually I started with ScrollView so had the VStack. i replaced it with a List because of performance (list has no hiccups but ScrollView has a lot when on iPad with many views). So I don't really need the VStack. The problem is that I have carousels in LazyHStacks. If I change to use Sections, then the carousels get all selected in the context menu instead of the specific item in the carousel. So actually my problem is with the HStack and I don't know if there is a replacement for that

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you wanted this:

[image: LazyHStack with context menu]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.horizontal) {
            LazyHStack {
                ForEach(0..<100) { index in
                    Button {
                        print("primary button")
                    } label: {
                        ZStack {
                            Color.red
                            Text("\(index)")
                        }
                        .contextMenu {
                            Button("option 1") {
                                
                            }
                            Button("option 2") {
                                
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .frame(width: 100)
                }
            }
        }
        .frame(height: 100)
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah this is with ScrollView instead of List, which I already know is working. unfortunately it seems like with List, context menu is broken when using inner LazyHStack.

Comment: It is not broken, with in a List the view is treated as a cell. LazyHStack / List wouldn't have performance issues as they render when needed.

Comment: The bug I refer to is that I put the context menu on the inner view inside the LazyHStack, but the whole LazyHStack is picked up by the gesture. That's a bug, it's not the expected behavior.

Comment: What @user1046037 said is correct. Though the .contextMenu is being "applied" to a stack inside your list, the list cell is the view which the context menu will be applied to. A list row is supposed to be your center of focus. Having multiple items inside a single list row is probably breaking some best practices.